# SwiftUI 2.0 iOS 14 Core data delete instance on button press

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, ios14, xcode12

I am trying to figure out how to delete an instance of a core data object by calling a method in my ViewModel. I managed to get the id of the instance to my method may be just struggling with the syntax. I'm using Xcode 12.3 iOS 14.3, SwiftUI 2.0 no more SceneDelegate or AppDelegate

Here is what my View Model looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class ViewModel : ObservableObject{
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(entity: Counter.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        
        NSSortDescriptor(
            keyPath: \Counter.id,
            ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(
            keyPath:\Counter.windowType,
            ascending: true )
    ]) var counters: FetchedResults<Counter>

    //.....
```

Below is what I have tried and got this error

+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Counter'

After stepping thru code in the debugger this is what I get when I print out CounterRequested

<NSFetchRequest: 0x282d70380> (entity: Counter; predicate: (id == "C4BE9AFF-8A8E-4413-AFA3-AC90850C482E"); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

the id's do match

Then it crashes on the first line in do block

```
func deleteCounter(id: UUID)  {
    let counterRequested: NSFetchRequest<Counter> = Counter.fetchRequest()
    counterRequested.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id=%@", id.uuidString)
  
    do {
        let savedCounters = try  self.viewContext.fetch(counterRequested)
        
        for counter in savedCounters {
            self.viewContext.delete(counter)
        }
        try self.viewContext.save()
    } catch {
      
        print(error)
    }
 }
}
```

Here is where I get my Id from. Can I pass the whole counter here? Not sure what type to reference in my counter view?

```
List {
       ForEach(counters, id: \.self){counter in
                    
          CounterCell(id: counter.id!, windowType: counter.windowType!, location: counter.location!, pickedImg: counter.pickedImg!, price: counter.price!, qty: counter.qty!, subtotal: counter.subtotal!) .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            leading: 0,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          bottom: 20,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          trailing: 0))
```

}

Here is my view where I want to call the delete method

```
struct CounterCell: View {
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
@State private var stepperValue = 0
@StateObject var estimatorData = EstimatorViewModel()

var id: UUID = UUID()
var windowType: String = "Window Type"
var location: String = "Location"
var pickedImg: String = "defaultImg"
var price: String = "0.0"
var qty: String = "0"
var subtotal: String = "0.00"

var body: some View {
   //.....
```

}

Here is an example I found:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataManager {
    
    static let shared = DataManager(moc: NSManagedObjectContext.current)
    
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    private init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.managedContext = moc
    }
    
    
    // Delete method
    // remove birthday
    func removeBirthday(id: UUID) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Birthday> = Birthday.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "id=%@", id.uuidString)
        do {
            let bdays = try self.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for bday in bdays {
                self.managedContext.delete(bday)
            }
            try self.managedContext.save()
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
    }
    
}

extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    static var current: NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my trying above I reached out to a senior developer and it turns out that it was the way I was accessing the managedObjectContext in my View Model. And in the process, I learned about accessing the shared persistenceController that is declared in the  Persistence file that's now included in the biolerplate SwiftUI Core Data App.

Here is the correct way in my case.

```
 var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext { PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext }
```

Here is my delete method

```
func deleteCounter(id: UUID)  {
    let counterRequested: NSFetchRequest<Counter> = Counter.fetchRequest()
    counterRequested.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "id=%@", id.uuidString)

    do {
        let savedCounters = try  self.viewContext.fetch(counterRequested)
        
        for counter in savedCounters {
            self.viewContext.delete(counter)
        }
        try self.viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Refactor

```
func deleteWindow(id: UUID)  {
    if let counter = existingCounter {
        viewContext.delete(counter)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While it’s good that you have found a solution I find it a bit strange that you need to fetch an object you most likely already have in memory and access to in your view and/or view model.

Comment: How would you have passed the whole counter?

Comment: Joakim Thanks again for your input

Comment: Have the counter object instead of the id (and some other properties) as a property in CounterCell. Then you can pass the object instead to the delete method. See my updated answer

Comment: Joakim Thanks I will give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your view model that deletes a given object.

Something like

```
func delete(counter: Counter) {
    do {
        viewContext.delete(counter)
        viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

---

I would update the view code somewhat and let CounterCell use a Counter property

```
struct CounterCell: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var stepperValue = 0
    @StateObject var estimatorData = EstimatorViewModel()

    var counter: Counter

    var body: some View {
   //.....
```

and change the ForEach accordingly

```
List {
   ForEach(counters, id: \.self) { counter in
      CounterCell(counter: counter) 
      //...
   }
```

}

Comment: Hi, Joakim thanks for your answer. At the moment I am only passing the Id and not the whole counter object. I suppose. I could refactor and send the whole object but would rather reference by id. I am going to have another go it today.

Comment: What I have is a forEach with a counter view I want to call the method in counter view

Comment: I am struggling with how to pass the whole object to my counter view not sure of what type of property  to reference in my counter view

Comment: I edited again to show what I have tried so far.

Comment: Joakim, Thanks again for the help I figured it out